# Can I have multiple Python fabfiles in one project directory?

Tags: python, fabric

I have a project that has a local copy in my machine and a remote copy in a server, **Server 1**. Currently, I use Fabric to update the remote copy when I make changes to my local copy. To do this, a fab file is located in the root directory of the project (e.g., `project/fabfile.py`).

I would like to use Fabric in this project for a second purpose. One of the functions in this project needs to connect to a different server, **Server 2**. Can I create a second fab file in the subdirectory of the project that contains the relevant code (e.g., `project/subdir/fabfile.py`)?

I am new to Fabric so I just want to make sure that I'm using Fabric in a way that won't cause the two fab files to interfere with each other.

Also, because I'm new to Fabric I may not be describing this situation appropriately. Please let me know if you need to know any additional information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have learned that a single fab file is enough for a project. Instead, it is best to have a single fab file that defines multiple functions that each make use of a different server. [Fabric documentation](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.10/usage/execution.html#defining-host-lists) offers a few ways to do this, depending on the specific needs of the user.

In my case, I modified my single fab file to look like this:

```
@hosts(server1)
def server1_task():
    ...

@hosts(server2)
def server2_task():
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

*I'm not 100% sure what you are trying to achive, but here is my thoughts.*

You don't usually need to upload your `fabfile`s to remote servers. It is better if you have keys from all machines you need to deploy to. You can operate them by using [hosts](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.10/usage/execution.html#defining-host-lists) or [roles](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.10/usage/execution.html#roles).

If also can use different `fabfile`s for different machines with [-f command line argument](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.10/usage/fab.html#cmdoption-f).

Let me know if I misunderstood you.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! :-) I'm afraid I wasn't the clearest in my question, but I was able to find an answer, which I have posted.

Answer (score 0):

You could put multiple python files intended to be used for fabric but you'll just have to call it with `-f`.

For example:

```
fab -f fabfile2 server2_task`
```

This could be useful for storing fabfiles with different purposes